# How to use preparedStatement with TeradataFastLoad Utility?

Tags: jdbc, teradata

Actually, I'm trying to insert the data into Teradata dynamically using the PreparedStatement using the following query:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(id,name,date) VALUES(?,?,?)
```

By, using the above query, it is failing to load the data into Teradata.
Here, in the above query, I'm trying to give all parameters dynamically without any manipulation.
Suppose,if I try to manipulate any of the parameter,I'm able to load the data.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(id,name,date) VALUES(?,?,cast(? as timestamp(0))
```

I have no idea, regarding why it is happenning like this?

Can anyone please help me out regarding this ...

Comment: When the `date` column has a `DATE` datatype the cast will fail due to the time part.When you cast it to a `TIMESTAMP` the insert will simply truncate the time part and succeed.

Comment: Eventhough, if it is not a date field also, it is unable to insert the data if all the three parameters are dynamic(?,?,?) without any manipulation

Comment: How does the input data look like?

Comment: suppose I have id,name,roll as the three parameters for the preparedstatement, the i/p data looks like 1,"Jai",205. And I need to give all these three parameters as the dynamic parameters instead of hardcoding

Comment: And how does `205` represent a Timestamp or Date?

Comment: This is another example dataset which I have mentioned above i.e, id,name,roll . So, the last field is roll but not date field

Comment: Did you read the JDBC examples? E.g. https://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/samp/T20208JD.java.txt

Answer (score 0):

May the column `date` datatype is not matching with the inserting table. And also `date` is a key word in Teradata